# Outlook ID from MapiEx

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

I'm developing c# application for copy Outlook emails starting from them MapiEx-EntryId. I need to retrieve Outlook.MailItem.EntryID using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `MailItem.EntryID` is the hex representation of the binary entry id stored in the `PR_ENTRYID` MAPI property.